# How do i disable the ctrl+click on an Apple Mouse

Tags: mac, mouse

I'm finding it hard playing my games because of the ctrl+click that apple made for 1 button mouses. Can anybody help me because it's not doing what i want it do, it just does a right-click.

Answer (score 1):

If your mouse really has two buttons, like the Mighty Mouse or Magic Mouse, just configure it as a two-button mouse under System Settings -> Mouse. Then, CTRL-Left click should be sent as such to applications.